# MS Access Show all records that are not as foreign key in other table

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Today I need again a little help.
I have a combobox, showing me all my users from my table 'tblUser'. The 'userID' is used in the table 'tblTime' as foreign key.

[image: This is my combobox]

Now what I would like to achieve is a filter for my combobox.
I want to have a filter for it, so it is only showing me the users that are NOT already in the 'tblTime'.

[image: This is the relationship between 'tblUser' and 'tblTime']

I think I need some kind of criteria for the combobox query in combination with the 'time' but i don't know how to do it and it is making me dizzy to think more and more about it

Please help me :(

[image: What kind of criteria, how to achieve it?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JOIN type should be:

```
LEFT JOIN
```

You can right-click on the join "line" between the two tables to preserve all the records in tblUser.  Then your criteria for timeID should be:

```
IS NULL
```

Comment: Stupid LEFT JOIN. Thank you very much. That's what I was looking for but I didn't know, how to perform the JOIN because I have always overlooked the "join" option at the "join" line.

It is now working :)

Comment: @Flouks:  Haha, no worries, man.  Very welcome.  You can also look at SQL view and just edit it from there.  Glad you got it working.